# Issues with node.js socket keep reconnecting

Tags: node.js, sockets, websocket, socket.io

I am having some unexpected behavior with socket.io in which I am experiencing un-prompted reconnection

Here is my frontend, which is referenced by index.html

```
$(function(){
    var socket = io.connect('https://localhost:3005', {'flash policy port':3005} );
});
```

Here is my backend

```
exports.listen = function(server){

    io = socketio.listen(server);
    io.set('log level', 2);

    io.set('flash policy port', 3005); 
    io.set('transports', [                     
        'websocket'
      , 'flashsocket'
      , 'htmlfile'
      , 'xhr-polling'
      , 'jsonp-polling'
    ]);

    io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket){
        console.log("This is the socket id");
        console.log(socket.id);
    });
}
```

Here is the output if I do nothing on the browser

```
This is the socket id
 gxn4mxnG9xOoVCLAoMPN
   warn  - websocket parser error: reserved fields must be empty
   info  - transport end (undefined)
   info  - handshake authorized 260xpHzgrsHd8UnNoMPO
This is the socket id
260xpHzgrsHd8UnNoMPO
   warn  - websocket parser error: reserved fields must be empty
   info  - transport end (undefined)
   info  - handshake authorized cMCv6BS-iLCQbmv6oMPP
```

it will keep connect and disconnect and reconnect until I shut down the server

I am not exactly sure why is it exhibiting this behavior, as I was under the impression that socket.io will not reconnect if you stay on the same page.

Any advice would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by uninstalling Node v0.10.9 and installing the latest version

For information to uninstall node please reference the link below with caution

http://notepad2.blogspot.com/2012/06/how-to-uninstall-nodejs-on-mac-os-x.html

For re-installation of node

Please check brew or macport

Also remember to update your brew/macport prior to installation